# How to render to a depth texture in OpenGL ES on Android

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-3

I need to render to a depth texture in Android, and I'm having trouble figuring it out. I've searched the web for several days and pieced together the following code:

```
  public void loadFrameBuffer(Context context, int resourceId) {
    final Bitmap bitmap = createBitmap(context, resourceId);

    // generate the framebuffer and texture object names
    glGenFramebuffers(1, frameBuffers, 0);
    glGenTextures(2, textures, 0);

    // bind color texture and load the texture mip level 0 texels are RGB565
    // no texels need to specified as we are going to draw into the texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[COLOR_TEXTURE]);
    texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, bitmap, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // bind depth texture and load the texture mip level 0
    // no texels need to specified as we are going to draw into
    // the texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[DEPTH_TEXTURE]);
    texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, bitmap, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    // bind the framebuffer
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffers[0]);

    // specify texture as color attachment
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
      GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[COLOR_TEXTURE],
      0);

    checkStatus();

    // specify texture as depth attachment
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
      GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[DEPTH_TEXTURE],
      0);

    checkStatus();
  }
```

checkStatus() for the color attachment is a success: GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE
however checkStatus() for the depth attachment is: GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT

The documentation for the error states:

> Not all framebuffer attachment points are framebuffer attachment
>   complete. This means that at least one attachment point with a
>   renderbuffer or texture attached has its attached object no longer in
>   existence or has an attached image with a width or height of zero, or
>   the color attachment point has a non-color-renderable image attached,
>   or the depth attachment point has a non-depth-renderable image
>   attached, or the stencil attachment point has a non-stencil-renderable
>   image attached.
>
> Color-renderable formats include GL_RGBA4, GL_RGB5_A1, and GL_RGB565.
>   GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16 is the only depth-renderable format.
>   GL_STENCIL_INDEX8 is the only stencil-renderable format.

I'm at a loss, even with this description as to what is wrong. The color attachment works just fine.

## EDIT:

I'm seeing this in the log just before the previously mentioned status error:

`<core_glTexImage2D:501>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION`

It appears to be because of this line of code:

`texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, bitmap, 0);`

## EDIT:

I got past the errors. I switched from the call to:

`texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, bitmap, 0);`

which is actually wrong, and now I'm calling:

`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, texWidth, texHeight, 0,
      GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GLES30.GL_FLOAT, null);`

which works. I don't see any more errors. However, I'm still having a problem.

Here's the model rendered straight to the default buffer (straight to the window):

[image]

But when I try to render the texture attached to my FrameBuffer mapped to the following:

```
// x, y, z, S, T
      new float[]{
        // left triangle
        -1f, -1f, 0f, 0f, 0f, //
        1f, 1f, 0f, 1f, 1f, //
        -1f, 1f, 0f, 0f, 1f, //

        // right triangle
        -1f, -1f, 0f, 0f, 0f, //
        1f, -1f, 0f, 1f, 0f, //
        1f, 1f, 0f, 1f, 1f //
      }
    );
```

It stretches the texture:

[image]

If I remove the left triangle and render I get this:

[image]

And lastly, rendering the depth texture gives me all red:

[image]

Comment: `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT` means that one of the attached images is not complete.  Is it possible that your device does not support the `OES_depth_texture` extension?  Note that depth textures are *not* part of the OpenGL ES 2.0 specification, they are an extension, and it is known that some devices do not support it.

Comment: Also, if your device supports `KHR_debug`, I highly recommend using it.  Register a logging callback with `glDebugMessageCallbackKHR()`.

Comment: How do I check if the device supports `OES_depth_texture`? Also, I'm testing this on a stock Nexus 5 running Android 5.0.1

Comment: Also, I'm using the Java version of OpenGL ES that comes with the Android SDK. I don't see a `glDebugMessageCallbackKHR()` method.

Comment: Hm, looks like a Nexus 5 should support depth textures, and doesn't support debug output.

Comment: I am seeing this in the logs: `<core_glTexImage2D:501>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION`

Comment: I'll add new findings to edits.

Comment: What is `texImage2D()`?  It doesn't look like an OpenGL call.  Why isn't it `glTexImage2D()`?

Comment: It's part of the Android SDK: See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLUtils.html#texImage2D(int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int))

Comment: Normally you would do something like `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, null)`...

Comment: When you pass null in to `glTexImage2D()` it creates a blank texture.

Comment: Ok, that appears to work if I call `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, null)`. I'm not seeing an invalid status. I'm still not clear on what to do with this afterwards.

Comment: Once the framebuffer is complete and bound to `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER` (or `GL_FRAMEBUFFER`), any drawing commands you issue will draw into that buffer.

Comment: It's now drawing, but the texture pixels are red instead of shades of grey (no pun intended).

Comment: I found the following comment on [this](https://www.talisman.org/opengl-1.1/Reference/glTexImage2D.html) page: "A one-component texture image uses only the red component of the RGBA color extracted from pixels. A two-component image uses the R and A values. A three-component image uses the R, G, and B values. A four-component image uses all of the RGBA components."

Comment: You shouldn't use that reference... that's out of date.  Use this instead: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/

Comment: I've gotten a little further, please check my updates on the question.

Comment: The output looks 100% correct to me (bright red in the back, with darker red in the front)... what exactly do you want it to look like?

Comment: Well, I want the color texture I grab from the FrameBuffer after the first render pass (1st image) to render exactly like the the first render pass without being stretched.

Comment: Also, should the brightness of the red tone vary across the surface of the image, given that the pixel depth varies? I'm rendering a 3D model which isn't a box. The front and back sides of the model have pieces that extrude outward to varying degrees. I should see a more varied depth in the depth render.

Comment: It does vary.  The variations are just more subtle than you expected.  This is probably due to a large depth range.  What is your depth range (zNear / zFar)?

Comment: Remember that it will be 100% red at zFar, and 100% black at zNear, so if zNear to zFar covers a large range, the depth buffer will be compressed.  This will also cause problems with depth buffer precision when rendering.

Comment: I'm using 1 for near and 40 for far in my perspective projection. Is there some optimal range? How does that relate to the min Z and max Z values of any particular model I load in?

Comment: If you want to increase the contrast in the depth buffer, you can use the largest zNear and smallest zFar values that don't clip your model.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Can you create an answer and explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Everything is working correctly, there is nothing to fix

Your depth texture is correct.  There is nothing left to fix.

The problem seems to be that you expect something with more contrast.  I downloaded your picture and enhanced the contrast in an image editor:

[image: Higher contrast image]

You can see that there are details in there!  A lot of data has been lost here, however.  Your screen probably has an 8-bit framebuffer at best, and then I download the result as a JPEG which quantizes it even further, but... the original depth texture itself is probably 16 bits.  So I can guess that we've probably lost ~10 bits by the time I've made the above image.

To put it another way, the depth buffer has 16 bits of precision, but the screen only has like 8.  So, of course you can't see the details.  The data is fine.

## Why is it red?

Of course it's red.  It's an image with only one channel.  If you want to color it differently, use texture swizzling, or apply a color in the fragment shader.